# How to check if my json array has missing objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am having and json file wich is created dynamicaly.

For example

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Bill",
            "surname": "Antony",
            "userPoints": 121,
            "wins": 11,
            "nationality": "English"
        },
        {
            "name": "George",
            "surname": "Peter",
            "userPoints": 1332,
            "wins": 11
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the second object is missing nationality field.
So in my code when i am printing with JS Jquery (.each). I am having an 'undedified' print for the second user. How can i check this before it's printed?

EDIT: I am adding the way i am printing the data:

```
function displayData(array) {
    var list = $("#list").empty();
    $.each(array, function () {
       $("ul").append('<li><span class="num">'+ if(this["nationality"]){ this["nationality"] }+'</span></li>');
    });
}
```

Comment: `if (user.nationality) { console.log(user.nationality)}`

Comment: Loop through it ahead of time and make sure none of the expected properties are undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty()`. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
if(users[0].hasOwnProperty('nationality')){

}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution! Is there anyway to make it search all the fields instead of doing it for one each time?

Comment: Well, somehow you need to know what properties to search for. If you know that, you can just iterate through the properties.

Comment: Ah allright, so i have to make multiple if statements. That's ok i guess! Thanks again!

Comment: Or you can put the properties in an array, and loop through that.

Answer (score 4):

`undefined` equates to false, so you can check the property of the object like this:

```
$.each(data.users, function(i, item) {
    if (item.nationality) {
        console.log(item.nationality);
    }
});
```

You could also shorten the `if` statement to this and get the same result:

```
item.nationality && console.log(item.nationality);
```

Comment: +1, I never knew `undefined == false`. Good information.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Yep, it's a handy quirk of javascript. More info: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: You can't use an if statement within a string concatenation like that.